# Passing arguments to a c executable from Python

Tags: python

I am trying to run an exe(my_executable) and parse the output to fetch some value .

```
 process = subprocess.Popen("./my_executable 3", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

but this is throwing error : ***No such file or directory: './my_executable 3'***

I even tried this :

```
 process = subprocess.Popen("./my_executable"," 3", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

***SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal***

how can I passs single or multiple arguments to subprocess?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your executable AND its arguments as single list:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["./my_executable", "3"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

PS: No need to add leading/separating spaces for the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options:

1. Create the argument vector yourself by passing `["./my_executable", "3"]` as the first argument.
2. Pass your invocation through the shell by specifying `shell=True` to `subprocess.Popen`, and have the shell create the argument vector for you.

Unless you want the shell to do something for you, like expanding `~` or something, I would go with the first option.